# Is magnitude of four-momentum of a massive particle at rest in a curved spacetime $= -c^2$?

Tags: general-relativity, momentum, metric-tensor, vectors

I know that for a massive particle traveling along its geodesic, the magnitude of its four-momentum is constant and is equal to  $-c^2$.
But for a particle at rest in a curved space time, i.e. it is not traveling along a geodesic, is the magnitude of momentum still $-c^2$?

Does the relation still hold?

Comment: The answer to your question is almost certainly "yes", but "at rest" is a tricky concept.

Comment: Note: the magnitude of the 4-monentum is $-mc^2$, i.e. proportional to the mass.

Comment: usually the length of the four vector is taken as seen here  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, the scalar magnitude of the 4-momentum is the same in SR and GR.  Although the magnitude-squared of the 4-momentum is $-(mc)^2$.

### vector magnitude in special relativity

The magnitude of the 4-momentum or any 4-vector comes from taking the dot product of the vector with itself.  In special relativity we use the Minkowski metric to calculate a dot product:
$$\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p} = p^\mu \eta_{\mu\nu} p^\nu,$$
where the components of the metric are
$$\eta_{\mu\nu} =
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and the components of the 4-momentum are $p^{\mu}=(E/c, p_x, p_y, p_z)$.  In the rest frame of a particle $E=mc^2$ and $p_i=0$ for all $i\in\{x,y,z\}$, so
$$\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p} = -(mc)^2.$$

Because vector magnitudes are scalars, this is true in any inertial reference frame.

This fact leads to the relativistic energy-momentum relation:
$$ -\left(\frac{E}{c}\right)^2 + {\bf p}^2 = -(mc)^2 $$
by comparing $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p}$ in any reference frame on the left-hand-side to the rest frame on the right-hand-side.  Here the bold ${\bf p}$ is the magnitude of the regular 3-momentum.

### vector magnitude in general relativity

To calculate the magnitude of vector in full GR, we do pretty much the same thing.  To calculate the dot product we need to use the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ which in general is not the flat Minkowski metric.
$$\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p} = p^\mu g_{\mu\nu} p^\nu$$

One of the great powers of GR is the fact that we can do any calculation in any coordinate system we want.  At any point in spacetime we can always form a momentarily co-moving reference frame (MCRF) where the particle is at rest.  By definition the metric of a MCRF is flat.  It is the metric of a surface tangent to the full spacetime at the point of interest.  In the MCRF the particle is at rest, so it has the same 4-momentum as in the special relativity case: $p^{\mu}=(mc, 0, 0, 0)$.  Since everything looks like SR in the MCRF, this leads to the exact same calculation.

$$\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p} = -(mc)^2$$

Again, since the magnitude is a scalar, it must be the same in all reference frames.

Comment: I down voted your question, but then I realized I did not read the OP question correctly. I apologize for that. There is no problem with your answer.

Comment: $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p} = (mc)^2 g_{tt}$ This can’t be true in all frames because the left side is a scalar while the right side is a scalar times one component of a tensor.

Comment: $p\cdot p$ is $-m^2$ in every frame, in both SR and GR.

Comment: @Thiago:  if you hit the upvote button, it will cancel your downvote without recording an upvote.

Comment: Thanks, WillO. I did not know that.

Comment: The conclusion in your last sentence is incorrect, because mass is not a Lorentz scalar in GR, but directly depends on the time dilation. To see this, consider an ideal weightless mirror box with massless photons. Its mass is $m=E/c^2$  where E is the energy of the photons. If this box hovers near a black hole horizon, the photons are redshifted to a near zero energy, so the mass of the box is asymptotically zero. 99% of the mass of the normal baryonic matter comes from the energy of (virtual) massless gluons, so the same logic applies to normal massive bodies.